# Making a full screen Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen

I want to create a full Screen Cocoa application, however my app is slightly different from a conventional fullscreen app.

This app would be below everything else, so underneath the menu bar and the Dock, etc. It would have a large image covering up the Desktop and icons, with a custom NSView in the middle with a table view, etc. If this concept is hard to understand then here is an image:

http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/6308/mockupo.png

The only part that might be a bit confusing is the background image. This background image is NOT the wallpaper of the computer, but part of the app. So when the app is launched, it goes into full screen mode and puts itself underneath the dock and the menu bar, and underneath all other windows too. So it draws the background image to cover the screen (including Desktop and icons). Then has a custom NSView in the middle containing my controls.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a borderless window, the size of the menu-bar screen (screen 0—**not** `[NSScreen mainScreen]`), positioned at 0,0, with window level `kCGDesktopWindowLevel`.

Remember that you will need to observe for screen frame-change notifications (when the user changes the screen dimensions), and that you should correctly handle the case of no screen at all (headless Mac).

Comment: Tried this and it does work to a certain extent. Issue is that other windows (e.g. Finder windows and other app windows) go below my full screen window. I need them to be positioned ABOVE my full screen window. Any ways to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Like I said, set the window level to `kCGDesktopWindowLevel`.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Peter Hosey’s solution should work, but to make other windows go on top, you will probably need to change the window level to something else.

But, I implore you, do not do this. This will be the most bugly application the Macintosh has ever seen. There are a lot of really good user interface paradigms that you can use, and "replicating" the main desktop interface of Mac OS X is generally not one of them. That is, unless you are reimplementing Time Machine or something like that.

Comment: This is not to be used as a normal OS X app. I'm using it as basically a desktop replacement for a minimal version of OS X I'm using as an emergency disk (has no Finder or Dock, so I need to make my own interface). I have tried setting the window level to NSDockWindowLevel but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Figured it out :) Set the window level to -1 and now it displays below all other windows :D.